# JavaScript - How to count each key value in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

JavaScript - How to count each key value in JSON?

```
[
  {date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1},
  {date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1},
  {date: "2017-09-28", type: "dot", count: 1},
  {date: "2017-09-26", type: "dot", count: 1}
]
```

with this JSON format to:

```
[
  {date: "2017-09-26", count: 1},
  {date: "2017-09-28", count: 3}
]
```

or

ultimately, to:

```
[
  {date: "2017-09-26", dot_count: 1, line_count: 0},
  {date: "2017-09-28", dot_count: 1, line_count: 2}
]
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Since you are looking to get a unique group count, you should loop the original map and create a new map with your conditionals as keys and increment the keys' value.

Comment: What I am to trying to do : first code was the original code and want to alter that to the third one with dot and line count. Ignore the count in the first code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table and create a new object if the hash does not exists. Later add the count value to the group.

```js
var data = [{ date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1 }, { date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1 }, { date: "2017-09-28", type: "dot", count: 1 }, { date: "2017-09-26", type: "dot", count: 1 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];
    
data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!hash[o.date]) {
        hash[o.date] = { date: o.date,  dot_count: 0, line_count: 0 };
        result.push(hash[o.date]);
    }
    hash[o.date][o.type + '_count'] += o.count;
});

result.sort(function (a, b) { return a.date.localeCompare(b.date); });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If count is always going to be 1, then you can remove it form the JSON and change the line hash[o.date][o.type + '_count'] += o.count; with hash[o.date][o.type + '_count'] += 1;

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b).

```
const test = [
  {date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1},
  {date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1},
  {date: "2017-09-28", type: "dot", count: 1},
  {date: "2017-09-26", type: "dot", count: 1}
];
let result = test.reduce((group, current) => {
    let index = group.findIndex(ele => ele.date === current.date);
    if (index === -1) {
        group.push(current);
        return group;
    } 
    group[index].count += current.count;
    return group;
}, []);
```

for your second level question you probably want to pair [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with reduce.

```
const test = [
      {date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1},
      {date: "2017-09-28", type: "line", count: 1},
      {date: "2017-09-28", type: "dot", count: 1},
      {date: "2017-09-26", type: "dot", count: 1}
    ];
const mapper = item => ({ 
    date: item.date, 
    dot_count: (item.type === 'dot') ? 1 : 0,
    line_count: (item.type === 'line') ? 1 : 0,
    total_count: item.count,
});
const reducer = (group, current) => {
    let index = group.findIndex(ele => ele.date === current.date);
    if (index === -1) {
        group.push(current);
        return group;
    } 
    group[index] = { 
        ...group[index], 
        dot_count: group[index].dot_count + current.dot_count,
        line_count: group[index].line_count + current.line_count,
        total_count: group[index].total_count + current.total_count,
    };
    return group;
};
let result = test.map(mapper).reduce(reducer, []);
console.log(result);
```